# Posting variables to a file in opencart

Tags: opencart

I would like to post some variables to a specific file in opencart. My problem is that I am not sure how to specify the file to post them to. This is my checkout.tpl file, inside the default template. I am trying to post the variable's to my confirm.tpl file, also in the default template. This is as close as i have got:

```
$('#button-account').live('click', function() {
                    var var1= $('#var1').val();
                    var var2= $('#var2').val();
                    $.post("catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/confirm.tpl", { quantity: quantity, total: total });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the MVC nature of OpenCart, you would actually need to post the results to a specific function in the controller configured to accept the ajax post, not the template.

Try reading the answer to [How to become an OpenCart guru?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru) that Jay Gilford provided. You might gain a better understanding of the system and how everything fits together.

The `add()` function of `checkout/cart` is configured for json, see if you can work it out from that.

```
$.post("catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/confirm.tpl", { quantity: quantity, total: total });
```

should probably read something like:

```
$.post("index.php?route=checkout/confirm/<function here>", { quantity: quantity, total: total });
```